# Spring - Need to make resultset scrollable

Tags: java, spring

I'm just executing the below code with one query but resultSet.isFirst() method is not working fine and getting error "The requested operation is not supported on forward only result sets." I believe this will work fine with scrollable result set.

```
public BillingTemplate extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        BillingTemplate billingTemplate = new BillingTemplate();
        List<String> contactAdditionalEmail = new ArrayList<String>();
        while(rs.next()){
          if(rs.isFirst()) { //This stateement is not working fine.
           //Code
          }
```

Could you please tell me how to make it scrollable or do I need to make any other change.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Pagination? Why do you need to test if the cursor is on the beginning of the result set?

Comment: There is a reason behind query holds multiple rows few records I've to assign only for first row but others it will be list.

Comment: It sounds like there is no need for a loop - just read the first row and ignore the rest.

Comment: No for last column i’ve to run the loop tht will be holding different data which i’ll be putting in to List for other columns data will be same so there no point to run the loop for those, there for i have to use both next() and isFirst()